# IF registro = X, LEFT JOIN na tabela 1, IF registro = Y, LEFT JOIN na tabela 2

Tags: mysql

Tenho uma tabela chamada "sistema_assinatura" contendo esses campos:
- TipoUsuario
- usuId

Esse usuId deverá guardar o ID de um usuário, obviamente. Mas esse usuário poderá ter 2 tipos (Aluno e Cliente). Os dados desses alunos e clientes são guardados em outra tabela.

**Basicamente minha necessidade seria isso:**

```
SELECT * FROM sistema_assinatura ass 
LEFT JOIN
    (CASE assTipoUsuario = 'A'
        THEN sistema_aluno a ON ass.usuId = a.aluId
    CASE assTipoUsuario = 'C'
        THEN sistema_cliente c ON ass.usuId = c.cliId)
```

Porém, obviamente isso não funcionou.

Algo assim é possível? Se sim, como proceder? Caso o tipo do aluno gravado no registro seja A, faz um JOIN na tabela "sistema_aluno". Se for tipo C, então o JOIN deverá ser na tabela "sistema_cliente".

Também tentei desta maneira:

```
SELECT * FROM sistema_assinatura ass 
(
    CASE WHEN assTipoUsuario = 'A' THEN LEFT JOIN sistema_aluno a ON ass.usuId = a.aluId
    CASE WHEN assTipoUsuario = 'C' THEN LEFT JOIN sistema_cliente c ON ass.usuId = c.cliId
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você tem que fazer o join com as duas, e os dados você seleciona o que precisa:

```
SELECT
ass.*,
(CASE WHEN ass.TipoUsuario = 'A' THEN 
   a.[campo]
 WHEN ass.TipoUsuario = 'C' THEN 
   c.[campo]
 ELSE '?' END) as tipoUsuario 
FROM sistema_assinatura ass
LEFT JOIN sistema_aluno a ON ass.usuId = a.aluId 
LEFT JOIN sistema_cliente c ON ass.usuId = c.cliId
```

**OU**

Utilizar Union:

```
SELECT
ass.*,
a.[campo]
FROM sistema_assinatura ass
LEFT JOIN sistema_aluno a ON ass.usuId = a.aluId 
WHERE ass.TipoUsuario = 'A'

union

SELECT
ass.*,
c.[campo]
FROM sistema_assinatura ass
LEFT JOIN sistema_cliente c ON ass.usuId = c.cliId 
WHERE ass.TipoUsuario = 'C'
```

Comment: Tentei utilizar a primeira opção, mas deu Syntax Error. A consulta ficou assim:
SELECT ass.*,
(CASE WHEN ass.TipoUsuario = 'A' THEN a.aluId
 CASE WHEN ass.TipoUsuario = 'C' THEN c.cliId
 ELSE '?' END
) 
AS tipoUsuario 
FROM sistema_assinatura ass
LEFT JOIN sistema_aluno a ON ass.usuId = a.aluId 
LEFT JOIN sistema_cliente c ON ass.usuId = c.cliId
E o erro: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CASE WHEN ass.TipoUsuario = 'C' THEN c.cliId
ELSE '?' END
) 
AS tipoUsuario 
FR' at line 3

Comment: perdoe, ficou com dois `CASE`. Veja agora

Comment: Perfeito, @Rovann Linhalis! Obrigado! Funcionou como uma luva!